# Batch: ( was not expected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know why do I get an error("( was not expected at this time") in this script.

```
for /f "delims=" %%t in (%cd%\Multitool\Multitool.txt) do (
set /p username=
set /p password=
set /p created=
)

if %created%==accountcreated ( goto CONTINUE ) else ( goto CREATE )
```

I have those lines of codes wich always get me an error: "( was not expected" at this time.

In my program I want to know if the user created an account already... 
When the user creates an account I echo this in %cd%\Multitool\Multitool.txt :

```
(
echo %username%
echo %password%
echo accountcreated
) > %cd%\Multitool\Multitool.txt
```

So can you tell me why I get that error and how to correct it please?
Sorry for my bad english im french...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

:: set up logfile and password 

SET "logfile=U:\q28542185.txt"
SET "password=dummypassword"
SET "myusername=dummyusername"

:: Dummy log entry

(
echo %myusername%
echo %password%
echo accountcreated
) > %logfile%

:: This is just to ensure the three variables are empty

FOR %%t IN (myusername password created) DO SET "%%t="


for /f "delims=" %%t in (%logfile%) do (
 SET "myusername=!password!"
 SET "password=!created!"
 SET "created=%%t"
)

if %created%==accountcreated ( goto CONTINUE ) else ( goto CREATE )

:continue
ECHO got to continue

GOTO :eof

:create
ECHO got to create

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28542185.txt` to receive the log information for my testing.

Note that `username` is a `magic variable` initialised by the syste, so I don't like changing it, so I've substituted `myusername`.

The first part sets up a dummy log file for testing.

The replacement `for` loop reads the log file and "ripples" the lines through the variablenames using the `delayedexpansion` facility, so that the variables are set in appropriate sequence.

Note that if `created` contains <kbd>Spaces</kbd> then your `if` statement should be modified to

```
if "%created%"=="accountcreated" ....
```

to allow correct parsing sequence `IF token operator token`